# Xcode gives plenty of Undefined Symbol: Firebase_App error

Tags: unity, ios, xcode, firebase

I Build my Unity project to Xcode, trying to install it on ios device. It gives errors like as follow

```
> Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_GetApps
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_RegisterLibrariesInternal
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_AdditionalUserInfoInternal_get
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_CredentialInternal_get
> 
> Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_UserInternal_get
> 
> Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_UserInternal_set
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_FirebaseAuth_CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordInternalAsync
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_FirebaseAuth_CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordInternalAsync_DEPRECATED
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_FirebaseAuth_SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialInternalAsync
```

totally gives 69 error like this.

I tried to add GameKit.framework, but still continue.

XCode version is: 14.3.1 (14E300c)
Firebase pod versions: 10.12.0, also I tried with 10.11.0 and 10.10.0
minimum ios version is:12.0
Unity Version is: 2021.3.16.
Firebase Unity SDK is: 11.1.0

and my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKGamingServicesKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FirebaseAuth', '10.11.0'
  pod 'FirebaseCore', '10.11.0'
  pod 'FirebaseDatabase', '10.11.0'
  pod 'FirebaseStorage', '10.11.0'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end
use_frameworks!
```

Can anyone assist me on this.